# How to open NetCDF in QGIS

Tags: qgis, netcdf, panoply

Despite the topic [Cannot open NetCDF File in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357159/cannot-open-netcdf-file-in-qgis), I cannot properly visualize my NetCDF file (nc4) in QGIS. It is quite strange because Panoply can do this (see image below). My NetCDF file visualize Standardized Precipitation Index (there are many results for the region of interest). It seems to me that I am able only to visualize it in some strange very narrow line if I loaded as raster.

This really doesn't help:

```
 Layer > Add Layer > Add Mesh Layer.
```

Error message:

```
Invalid Data Source: C:\Users\lukat\Downloads\IMERG_spi_gamma_03.nc is not a valid or recognized data source.
```

[image: Panoply result]

Comment: What version of netCDF is your data? Version <=3 and 4 are different in their internal structure.

Comment: Format of the file is nc4

Comment: Do you have GDAL installed alongside with QGIS (e.g. via osgeo4w)? If so, what does gdalinfo say about the file?

Comment: I run GDAL ruster information inside QGIS. I am not quite sure if I have some stand-alone version except in python and output has 1014 lines. It starts with Warning 1: Recode from UTF-8 to CP_ACP failed with the error: "Invalid argument".
Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format. Should I run

Comment: *Should I run it through some script?

Comment: I may be wrong, but if you are trying to follow this [NASA training course material](https://arset.gsfc.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/water/20-IMERG/IMERG_Week2_FINAL.pdf) material by Amita Mehta and Sean McCartney, you will find how to fix your `very narrow line` on the slide# 31 .

Comment: Thx! I will try it and give you feedback here. Actually I was doing this tutorial :D Haha

Comment: @Kazuhito Great! It is working! I've skipped this part because I've thought that I've already done it before, however It is little bit different. approach. So yes, You need to change the order of lat, lon and time. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to know that you've fixed it. It's nice tutorial, I would like to try it myself.

Comment: @Kazuhito If you would like to answer my question, I will gladly recommend it! ;-)

Comment: Much appreciate it. But, honestly I have no skill to reproduce the issue (and the successful outcome). Would be great if you could post the workflow. It will help others who follows the steps. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved my issue with the help of **@Kazuhito**.

Firstly, you need to install the NCO (netCDF Operator). The issue is that NetCDF has sometimes different order of variables and QGIS is not able to recognize and match right variables (so it is reading time as longitude).

The NCO command as follows should change variables to the right order for QGIS:

```
ncpdq -a time,lat,lon IMERG_spi_gamma_03.nc spi_gamma_03_mozambique.nc
```

Comment: please mark your own answer as the solution ✅

Comment: How do I install the "NCO"?  Do I download it from some web source?  I couldn't find it in the QGIS plugin repository.

Comment: The NCO is best to obtain through the Anaconda distribution ;-)

Comment: To get NCO, if you already have conda, enter this into the command line:
conda install -c conda-forge nco

Comment: NCO website with download links: https://nco.sourceforge.net/
Still didn't work for GMRT bathymetry data though, NETCDF GMT v3 grd file.